# iterator default constructor and POD member initialization

Tags: c++, iterator, default-constructor

From an example [1] in the documentation for boost::iterator_facade:

```
class node_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade< /* ... */ >
{
 public:  node_iterator() : m_node(0) { } 
          /* ... */
 private: node_base* m_node;
};
```

Followed by a footnote:

> > > Technically, the C++ standard places almost no requirements on a default-constructed iterator, so if we were really concerned with efficiency, we could've written the default constructor to leave m_node uninitialized.

My question (two parts): 

(a) What requirements does the C++ standard place on a default-constructed iterator?

(b) Why would leaving out `m_node(0)` avoid initializing `m_node` when instantiating a `node_iterator`? Wouldn't `m_node` then be default-initialized (thus zero-initialized) anyway?

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#constructors-and-data-members
(nb: Although this question originated from a boost example, I believe it applies to STL iterators, thus I did not use a "boost" tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would leaving out m_node(0) avoid initializing m_node when instantiating a node_iterator?

Just because the default constructor for a `node_iterator` is called does not mean that the non-static data-members of the class itself are properly initialized, especially if no initialization is specified for those data-members.  This includes omitting those non-static data-members from the constructor initialization list.  Furthermore, `m_node` is a pointer, and therefore a POD-type, thus it does not have a default-constructor that would be called to construct the object before entering the body of the constructor for `node_iterator` itself. Therefore omitting `m_node` from the initializer list would avoid specifically initializing the `m_node` data_member.

> Wouldn't m_node then be default-initialized (thus zero-initialized) anyway?

Per the C++03 spec, section 8.5/9, a non-static object (which also includes a non-static data-member of a class) is initialized with an "indeterminant" value if no initializer is specified for that object.  A non-static object is only default-initialized if it is a non-POD class type and/or a const-qualified type.  In this case `m_node` is a pointer-type, and is therefore a POD-type, so it is not zero-initialized ... it's just "initialized" with whatever pre-existing value was in memory at the location of the variable, thus making it an "indeterminant" value that it's initialized with.

Comment: thanks! So to explicitly default-initialize a non-const POD-type, I would have to use the value-initialization syntax `m_node()`? Also, do you have a reference in the spec for the (a) part of my question?

Comment: Yes, the preferred way would be to use the value-initialization syntax in the constructor's initialization list. C++11 also introduces some other new ways a non-static member can be initialized.  The other alternative is to make sure that you set the value for the variable in the constructor body, but that's generally not preferred since the initialization list is executed before entering the constructor body, and skipping the initialization list forfeits that guaranteed initialized state of the class before entering the constructor.